# Updating a table based on a query of the same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table which stores information on standings in multiple leagues, think of this as a fantasy site. The structure is as follows in terms of columns.

```
league_id | user_id | total_points | prediction_difference | current_position | last_position
```

In order to calculate the current standings I am issuing the following query:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM f_u_standings 
WHERE league_id = 1 
ORDER BY total_points DESC,
    prediction_difference DESC
```

My question is, now I have this result set, how can I then perform an `UPDATE` based on the `SELECT` query which updates the current_position column? My programming language of choice on this project is PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can update with a select.. this assumes you have an ID for each row

```
UPDATE TABLE f_u_standings fs, 
(
    SELECT 
        * 
        ----- do what you want to change current_position -----
    FROM f_u_standings 
    WHERE league_id = 1 
    ORDER BY total_points DESC,
        prediction_difference DESC
) temp
SET fs.current_position = temp.current_position WHERE fs.id = temp.id
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, the query appears to complete without error and says it's updated two rows (test data) but the current_position value isn't updated. The query is as follows... `UPDATE f_u_standings fs,
(SELECT * FROM f_u_standings WHERE league_id = 1 ORDER BY total_points DESC, prediction_difference DESC) temp
SET fs.current_position = temp.current_position WHERE fs.id = temp.id`

Comment: @MartynCoup i will need to see some sample data to help any more because this does a select of all rows, and then sets the current_position by the id, so it should be on the correct rows

Comment: My bad, I have it now, I was just getting the current value instead of changing it!

Comment: Ah gotcha! glad I could help! :)

Comment: Hang on, won't that set the `current_position` to the exact same as the old `current_position`?

Comment: @Arth no,.. not if the OP is changing the current value.. see his comment.. this was just getting the current value.. he did not provide part of the query where he makes changes to it so I didn't include that in my query

Comment: @JohnRuddell OK, but it seems you have left out the hard part.

Comment: @Arth ... i did not leave out the hard part. the OP said he already got the result set he wanted and didn't know how to update his table with that result set. his comment `My bad, I have it now, I was just getting the current value instead of changing it!` shows that he had the query already set and just didn't change it over to that query when running this update... his post `My question is, now I have this result set, how can I then perform an UPDATE based on the SELECT query which updates the current_position column?` shows that he already got his desired result set.........................

Comment: @JohnRuddell Ah, I thought he was using the order of the select to determine the current position of the row, hence my answer.

Comment: @Arth well he has a previous position and a current position.. these positions are not rownumbers but more something on the lines of a baseball players position. so he may be setting a new position and changing the previous position to the current position or something.. but yea it wasn't clarified in the question so i ommitted that from the query :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell That makes a lot more sense, my apologies.

Comment: @Arth no trouble at all lol... its hard to explain things on here without getting super specific

Answer (score 1):

This may be closer to what you need:

```
  UPDATE f_u_standings fs, 
         (SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, id
            FROM f_u_standings, (SELECT @rownum := 0) init
           WHERE league_id = 1 
        ORDER BY total_points DESC,
                 prediction_difference DESC) temp
     SET fs.current_position = temp.rownum
   WHERE fs.id = temp.id
```

Comment: I would recommend instantiating @rownum := 0 with a cross join before doing calculations on it.. that way you know you aren't getting incorrect results. but the rownum has nothing to do with this question :)